# Using memcache to store obj's in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm trying to use memcache to cache data retrevied from the datastore. Storing stings works fine. But can't one store an object? I get an error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" when trying to store with this:

```
pageData = StandardPage(page)    
memcache.add(memcacheid, pageData, 60)
```

I've read in the documentation that it requires "The value type can be any value supported by the Python pickle module for serializing values." But don't really understand what that is. Or how to convert pageData to it.

Any ideas?

..fredrik

**EDIT:**

I was a bit unclear. PageType is an class that amongst other thing get data from the datastore and manipulate it. The class looks like this:

```
class PageType():
    def __init__(self, page):
        self.pageData = PageData(data.Modules.gql('WHERE page = :page', page = page.key()).fetch(100))
        self.modules = []

    def renderEditPage(self):
        self.addModules()
        return self.modules



class StandardPage(PageTypes.PageType):
    templateName = 'Altan StandardPage'
    templateFile = 'templates/page.html'

    def __init__(self, page):
        self.pageData = PageTypes.PageData(data.Modules.gql('WHERE page = :page', page = page.key()).fetch(100))
        self.modules = []
        self.childModules = []

        for child in page.childPages:
            self.childModules.append(PageTypes.PageData(data.Modules.gql('WHERE page = :page', page = child.key()).fetch(100)))

    def addModules(self):
        self.modules.append(PageTypes.getStandardHeading(self, 'MainHeading'))
        self.modules.append(PageTypes.getStandardTextBox(self, 'FirstTextBox'))
        self.modules.append(PageTypes.getStandardTextBox(self, 'SecondTextBox'))
        self.modules.append(PageTypes.getStandardHeading(self, 'ListHeading'))
        self.modules.append(PageTypes.getStandardTextBox(self, 'ListTextBox'))
        self.modules.append(PageTypes.getDynamicModules(self))
```

Comment: Can you please include the full stacktrace? Nothing you've pasted would explain the exception you're reporting.

Comment: You are right, it was in a other method that failed. I used a instance of another class (witch wasn't needed) or change it to data={}. And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `db.model_to_protobuf` to turn your object into something that can be stored in memcache. Similarly, `db.model_from_protobuf` will get your object back.

**Resource:**

[Datastore Functions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html)

Comment: Thanks. But I realize that I was a bit unclear. I will edit my question above.

Comment: What is the exact error that is getting thrown? I'm thinking that it is `pageData = StandardPage(page)` and you have a scope error in your code. If not, what is the output of `print type(PageData)` after the first call?